# SonarQube 6.7.4 incremental scan

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

We are evaluating how incremental Sonar static code analysis can be achieved. We usually do full code quality check and post the results on Sonarqube dashboard. The requirement is to run incremental scan on the modified changes from Git repository. My concern is results will be overwritten every time incremental scan is executed. Is there a way to resolve that issue?  I need to have full report and also delta scan results (on every build) on Sonarqube project. Is it possible?